# Atom 1.29.0 Won't run Java program

Tags: java, atom-editor, javac

I am trying to run a simple Java program in Atom, with no success. 
My code:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I use the cmd-i shortcut to run the code, and get the following error:

javac: invalid flag: /Users/xxxxx/Desktop/Programming/Atom (text editor)/AtomPrograms/AAA first test
Usage: javac  
use --help for a list of possible options
[Finished in 0.586s]

Comment: I do not know how you should configure it, so this is just a comment: as the path contains spaces, the entire thing should be surrounded with ```"```, it has to refer an actual file, preferably with .java extension, it should be present in the command, and you may need ```\```-s instead of ```/```-s. So ```javac \Users\...\AAA first test\Hello.java```

Comment: Oh, I did not add the quotes :s, so: ```javac "\Users\...\AAA first test\Hello.java"```.

Answer (score 0):

The file did not have the same name as the class name. 
It runs now. 
Thank you